# mvc do you use model for websites with only static pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

This might be a stupid question, but I am new to MVC (I have used Webforms plenty) and was watching a tutorial video that stressed how the model should do all the heavy lifting in an application and how the model is way more than just specifying a type of data.

My question is, if I am building a normal (meaning... typical) website, let's say just a personal website, which doesn't have much user interaction with it or maybe it has a Contact page where it sends an email or something but nothing involving a database or really much data/computation, what role do models really play?

thanks a lot for your thoughts!

Comment: Build/Use X when you absolutely need X !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Model's job is to represent the problem domain, maintain state, and provide methods for accessing and mutating the state of the application.

For example in your website if you have a contact form like you said above your MVC pattern would be this

Model

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Contact {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View (wont include all the fields)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contact-form", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-div-1">
            <label class="name">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "First Name *", @type = "text" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-2">
            <label class="email">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email Address *", @type = "email" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="button">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(MailModels e)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(e.Email.ToString());
            message.Append("First Name: " + e.FirstName + "\n");
            message.Append("Email: " + e.Email + "\n");
            // send email logic below
        }
    }
```

Now with this basic example can you see how important and good it is to have that logic split up.

Models simply provide a nice abstraction for your data. Instead of thinking in terms of "how do I write this inner join to get all the fields I need", models enable you to think in terms of "how are my application's objects related to each other, how do they interact and how can I get the data I need from them".

> The central component of MVC, the model, captures the application's
>   behavior in terms of its problem domain, independent of the user
>   interface. The model directly manages the application's data, logic
>   and rules

So yeah basically the Model is the biggest, most important layer in most MVC applications.

Comment: what about pages that are just static like about or pictures or something. i am correct in assuming that they dont need models, right? or am i missing something? Like the commend to my question says, if there is no need for a model, i shouldnt use one, right?

Comment: yeah if you dont have any data to manipulate or anything you just don't need to use the model but then you should maybe re-think and use webforms if thats the case.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much. your answer above is perfect too!

Comment: No worries mate :)